# Replace all dot without special rules

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string is:

`2012.2008.The.Victorias.Secret.Fashion.Show.2016.720p.HDTV.x264-HD.MA.5.1 21d.BATV <6>-20`

I want to replace all dot to space but without '5.1', how can i write the regex string?

the `5.1` may be `6.1`, `7.1` `2.1`, one number before dot and one number after dot, and `234.123` need replace dot to space.

I give some string below:

`Cast.Away.2000.1080p.Blu-ray.AVC.DTS-HD.MA.5.1-XOXO-HDSky`
the `5.1` do not replace, other need replace
`Resident.Evil.The.Final.Chapter.2016.BluRay.1080p.AVC.DTS-HD.MA7.1-LKReborn-CHDBits` 
the `7.1` do not replace, other need replace

Comment: "but without '5.1'" is not a clear rule. What's with `2.2` and `6.7`, should they match or not?

Comment: It would be impossible without more rules. what if your file included 2015.1080p. That's a 5.1 that should be changed...

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin my means the rule is:　`d{1} . d{1}` do not replace, but the digital before the dot more than one  or after the dot more than one need to replace.

Comment: @William_Wilson when 2005.1080p the dot need to space, only d{1}.d{1} do not replace

Comment: @revo, a sample `Resident.Evil.The.Final.Chapter.2016.BluRay.1080p.AVC.DTS-HD.MA7.1-LKReborn-CHDBits` i want to replace all dot to space without  `7.1` in this string. I want get result `Resident Evil The Final Chapter 2016 BluRay 1080p AVC DTS-HD MA7.1-LKReborn-CHDBits`

Comment: Have you tried any thing? BTW below answer has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match 5.1 or 7.1 and capture the other dots in captured group 1:

[`[57]\.1\b|(\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/OFJVZK/1)

In using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) you could check if the submatch is equal to the dot.

```js
const strings = [
  "Resident.Evil.The.Final.Chapter.2016.BluRay.1080p.AVC.DTS-HD.MA7.1-LKReborn-CHDBits",
  "2012.2008.The.Victorias.Secret.Fashion.Show.2016.720p.HDTV.x264-HD.MA.5.1 21d.BATV <6>-20",
  "Cast.Away.2000.1080p.Blu-ray.AVC.DTS-HD.MA.5.1-XOXO-HDSky"
];
let pattern = /[57]\.1\b|(\.)/g;
strings.forEach((str) => {
  console.log(str.replace(pattern, function(match, p1) {
    return p1 === "." ? " " : match;
  }));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I change the pattern to `/[0-9]\.[0-9]\b|(\.)/g`, all looks is ok, is it right?

Comment: @taobataoma It is a somewhat broader match but for your example data it works. [`[0-9]\.[0-9]\b|(\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/CzufWK/1) It could for example also match 9.9.

Comment: it is not problem, I accept this result. in some special things,  i can modify this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this [`string.replace` with a callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
let str = '2012.2008.Resident6.1.Evil 4.3.The 7.8 .Final.Chapter.2016.BluRay.1080p.AVC.DTS-HD.MA.5.2-LKReborn, get the result 2012 2008 Resident6.1 Evil 4.3 The 7.8 Final Chapter 2016 BluRay 1080p AVC DTS-HD MA.5.2-LKReborn';

var re = /((?:^|\D)\d\.\d(?=\D|$))|\./g;

var repl = str.replace(re, function($0, $1) {
  return ($1 ? $1.replace(/^\./, ' ') : ' ');
});

console.log(repl);
```

Here regex `/((?:^|\D)\d\.\d(?=\D|$))|\./` matches and captures `digit.digit` in captured group #1. In the callback function we check presence of `$1` (captured group #1) to figure whether to replace match with space or `$1` (with initial dot being replaced by space).

Comment: thank a lot, I test your code, and input for `Resident.Evil.The.Final.Chapter.2016.BluRay.1080p.AVC.DTS-HD.MA7.1-LKReborn-CHDBits`, but it is replace all dot, include the dot in `7.1`, how to keep the dot in `7.1`?

Comment: Thank you very much. It's close to perfection, only a little question, if input is `Resident.Evil.The.Final.Chapter.2016.BluRay.1080p.AVC.DTS-HD.MA.7.1-LKReborn-CHDBits`, Normally, maybe a space or a dot before `7.1`, how modify it?

Comment: If you have newer browsers then you can use: `/((?<=^|\D)\d\.\d(?=\D|$))|\./g`

Comment: hi, I got a eslint error: Parsing error: Error parsing regular expression: Invalid regular expression: /((?<=^|\D)\d\.\d(?=\D|$))|\./: Invalid group, How to edit it? thanks. it works normal, only a lint error.

Comment: en, now I write a lang string to test it `2012.2008.Resident6.1.Evil 4.3.The 7.8 .Final.Chapter.2016.BluRay.1080p.AVC.DTS-HD.MA.5.2-LKReborn`, get the result `2012 2008 Resident6.1 Evil 4.3 The 7.8  Final Chapter 2016 BluRay 1080p AVC DTS-HD MA.5.2-LKReborn`, the last `.5.2` it is not ok.

Comment: You can see in demo above, it returns `MA 5.2-LKReborn` in the end

Comment: yes, you are right, It seems that the answer to @ The fourth bird is a bit simpler

Comment: If input is `'2012.2008.abc MA.5.2LKReborn'` then that regex would make it `"2012 2008 abc MA 5 2LKReborn"` instead of `"2012 2008 abc MA 5.2LKReborn"`